# Initialize a Generic Type property

Tags: c#

I have the following class:

```
  public class Payload<T> {

    public T Result { get; set; } = new T();

    public Payload() { }

  }
```

I am getting the error on `new T();`:

```
Cannot create an instance of the variable type 'T' because it does not have the new() constraint
```

How to initialize a Generic Type property?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add a `new()` constraint on `T`, this makes sure that only types that have a public parameterless constructor can be used as type argument:

```
public class Payload<T> where T: new() {

    public T Result { get; set; } = new T();

    public Payload() { }

 }
```

More info: [new constraint (C# Reference)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/new-constraint)

Answer (score 1):

There are some options:

1. If You don't know the type of `T` in compile-time and you need the run-time resolution of the type you can use [Activator.CreateInstance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.activator.createinstance?view=net-5.0).

> Creates an instance of the specified type using the constructor that best matches the specified parameters.

```
public T Result { get; set; } = Activator.CreateInstance<T>();
```

Note, it is calling the default constructor of your type and therefore, you will need to have a parameterless constructor. With `Activator.CreateInstance<T>` you can also call constructors with parameters (what you can't do in section 3 below).

2. If you need just a default value you can simply use the `default(T)`.

```
public T Result { get; set; } = default(T);
```

3. If you want to ensure that the `T` has a parameterless constructor in compile-time, you can add a `new` constraint.

```
public class Payload<T> where T: new() {
    public T Result { get; set; } = new T();
    ...
```

Comment: This will throw if the type T doesn't have a public parameterless constructor. If that's a requirement, it's better to put it in as a type constraint, like the other answer says. And then you can say `new T()`.